# gcloud installed on gce instance with service level accounts permission issues

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I launched an instance with service level accounts enabled.  For example it has storage-rw set.  I verfied that the instance has those.  Now whenever i run gsutil ls gs://my_bucket from within the instance I get the error: Failure: unauthorized_client.

gcloud auth list returns

```
Credentialed accounts:
 - xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com (active)
```

I need to use gcloud sdk from an instance because i need more components other than the gcutil and gsutil.

So my question is how can I authorize gcloud to use the xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com account and thus the permissions only specified on the instance and not my personal user account which has full permissions to everything?

Comment: Could it be a bucket-level permission issue? Just because your service account has rw access to storage doesn't necessarily give it bucket access. Can you create buckets from your instance?

Comment: Is the billing status active on your project?

Comment: @user3385351 - no i cannot even create a bucket.  Same error unauthorized client.

Comment: @jterrace yes its enabled.

Answer (score 6):

The gcloud CLI definitely handles Google Compute Engine service accounts. If you see it as "(active)" when you do `$ gcloud auth list`, that should be sufficient.

Two things can be going wrong here:

1. You are using the wrong gsutil.

   When you install the Google Cloud SDK, it will create `google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil`, and THAT is the one you want to run. Do `$ which gsutil` to double check. If you're running `google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil`, that's the wrong one, and it won't know about anything that gcloud can tell it.
2. The account doesn't have permissions to access the bucket you're trying to inspect. You'll have to ask the owner of the bucket to add it to the project that owns that bucket.

*Source: Engineer for the Google Cloud SDK*

Comment: John which gsutil returns /home/web/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil.  So that looks good.

Comment: John 1) which gsutil returns /home/web/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil.  So that looks good I think. 2) If i launch an instance and do not install gcloud sdk i can read the bucket fine with the default gsutil installed and the service permissions set to read write. with cloud sdk installed I cannot create a bucket or read any buckets. I also cannot list cloudsql instances with gcloud sql instances list.  I verifed that I can access cloud sql from that instance and that its external ip is allowed on the cloudsql server.  The instance permissions are cloudsql= enabled.  storage = read write. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

See "Authenticating to Google Compute Engine" section in this doc: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/

Comment: Nope thats authenticating using a personal account.  I need gcloud and all of its components to use the xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com not personal accounts which have too many permissions

Comment: The link provide doesn't have a "Authenticating to Google Compute Engine" section, which is why it's recommended practice to include details in your answer rather than just a reference.